# differences between 'developing' and 'developed'

Tags: word-choice

> We need all-round developing youths in our country
>   We need all-round developed youths in our country

Which is correct ?

Comment: Can we use develop with person ?

Comment: What are you trying to say using "developing" or "developed"? How else would you phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

Developing means the things are still under development and not achieved the final goal or status.

Developed means the things are done and achieved the goal or status.

China is a developing country.

The U.S. is a developed Country.